# Find the limit of √x^2/x as x approaches zero from the left.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

For each of the following, use definitions (rather than limit theorems) to prove that the limit exists. Identify the limit in each case.

a) lim_x→ 0^(-) = √x^2/x

proof: Suppose f(x) = √x^2/x, and L = -1. Then f(x) → -1 as x →  0^(-)[zero from the left].

Then by definition, f(x) is said to converge to 0^(-) [zero from the left] if and only if f is defined on some open interval I with right endpoint a, and for every ε > 0 there is an δ > 0 such that a - δ < x < a implies |f(x) - L| < ε. In which case we call L the left hand limit of f at a denoted by f(a^-) := L.

Then let ε > 0. Then by definition there exists δ > 0, s.t 
0 - δ < x < 0 or - δ < x < 0  implies |√x^2/x - (-1)| < ε.

Can someone please help me finish? Thank you for everything.

Comment: Saying what the limit is is not the same as proving that is actually the limit...

Comment: There is an example like that in the book.

Comment: The comment remains, @user, unless you can justify in an exam saying that there's an example in a book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of:

$$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=-x\;,\;\;\text{if}\;\;x<0\implies \lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}x=\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{-x}x=\lim_{x\to 0^-}-1=-1$$

Comment: That is better, thanks. When choosing my ε can I say ε = δ?

Comment: Yes @user3263, but drop that $\;\left|\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}x+1\right|<\epsilon\;$ thing, and write directly $$\sqrt{x^2}=-x\;,\;\;\left|\frac{-x}x+1\right|=|-1+1|=0$$and you get something really trivial.